# "No virtual method ~~" error occurs if the suspend modifier is removed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am writing code to fetch data from `Room`.

as shown in the image below, the IDE indicates that `suspend` is a useless modifier.
[image]

So, if I remove `suspend`, the following error occurs.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.lightweight, PID: 6483
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getWorkoutList(Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/example/lightweight/data/repository/WorkoutListRepository; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.example.lightweight.data.repository.WorkoutListRepository' appears in /data/data/com.example.lightweight/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes13.dex)
        at com.example.lightweight.presentation.viewmodel.WorkoutListViewModel$getList$1.invokeSuspend(WorkoutListViewModel.kt:23)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@6975010, Dispatchers.IO]
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6483 SIG: 9
```

However, if I leave `suspend` as is, it runs normally. For what reason?

---

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface WorkoutDao {
    @Query("SELECT * From WorkoutListTest")
    fun getWorkoutList() : List<WorkoutListTest>

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class WorkoutListViewModel(
    private val repository: WorkoutListRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _list = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val list: LiveData<List<String>>
        get() = _list


    fun getList() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getWorkoutList()
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class WorkoutListRepository(private val dao: WorkoutDao) {
    fun getWorkoutList() : List<WorkoutListTest> {
        val list: List<WorkoutListTest> = dao.getWorkoutList()
        return list
    }
}
```

**The part that uses ViewModel in Fragment.**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    vm.getList()
    vm.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { list ->

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your DAO function is not marked suspend. Since the DAO function is a regular synchronous, blocking function, calling through to it in your suspend function doesn't take advantage of the `suspend` modifier. Incidentally, this would also mean your suspend function is blocking, which breaks convention and would cause your coroutines to block threads incorrectly. But the Kotlin compiler cannot detect that the DAO function is blocking, so the warning message doesn't mention that.

You need to mark your DAO function `suspend`:

```
@Dao
interface WorkoutDao {
    @Query("SELECT * From WorkoutListTest")
    suspend fun getWorkoutList() : List<WorkoutListTest>
}
```

You said that leaving `suspend`, it ran normally. This is because you launched your coroutine using `Dispatchers.IO`. But you shouldn't have to use `Dispatchers.IO` unless you're calling a blocking function. By convention, suspend functions never block. So if you were following conventions, you would not use `Dispatchers.IO` to call a suspend function, but then your incorrectly blocking suspend function would hang the main thread.

---

Side note, there's a much easier way to fetch an item from a suspend function one time to fill in a LiveData. Your ViewModel class could be changed to the following and it would have the exact same behavior:

```
class WorkoutListViewModel(
    private val repository: WorkoutListRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val list: LiveData<List<String>> = liveData {
        emit(repository.getWorkoutList())
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks However, the [codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordsApplication.kt) does not use suspend.
Is this related to Flow?

Comment: I don't have time to read through all their code. If you return a Flow from a DAO, it doesn't make sense to use `suspend` because the Flow itself can be generated immediately without blocking. The suspension happens under the hood of the Flow, *when it is collected*.

Comment: I changed `getWorkoutList()` to `suspend` and got the error `error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`

Comment: What is your return type?

Comment: um.. it's a `List<WorkoutListTest>`

Comment: I thought maybe you had changed it because I remember it being fully compatible to either use `suspend` or not if the rest of the signature is the same.. Not sure what's wrong. Your other option is to leave it non-suspending in the DAO, and make your repository function look like `suspend fun getWorkoutList() : List<WorkoutListTest> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { dao.getWorkoutList() }`. So in this case, the DAO function is blocking, and the Repository function calls the blocking function on Dispatchers.IO, so it is a proper suspending function where callers can call it from any dispatcher.

Comment: `withContext()` also doesn't work. i still got the same error.

Assuming the code of `ViewModel` is as I posted,
I'll write a case where it works.

**1.** When both `DAO` and `Repository`'s `getWorkoutListTest()` are not `suspend`

**2.** If only `getWorkoutListTest()` of `Repo` is `suspend`. This is the code I asked yesterday. However, strangely, the error written in the OP does not occur today.

In conclusion, I thought that returning `List<>` without using suspend in `DAO` would cause an error, but that doesn't seem to be the case either.
I just feel comfortable using `Flow`.